# How to compose an MMS with an audio file programmatically in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm interested in seeing working code for how to compose an SMS/MMS programmatically using the latest iOS in order to include a sound file, taking into consideration that if the file is too big (unsure of the max size at this time, any info is appreciated) an error should be displayed to the user.

I know this can be done, because the built-in recorder for the apple iphone allows for sending audio files via a text message if they're not too big. I'd like to understand how it achieves this programmatically, what sound formats are available to me and what are the limitations if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to send MMS through the MessageUI framework, which is the framework iOS allows developers to interact with the Messaging interface. Apple uses private APIs in their apps, and any use of private APIs = automatic rejection in the App Store.

Comment: if they are providing facility to add attachment so why we can not send attachment with messageUI framework??

Answer (score 1):

Raphael is right, there is currently no way in the current iOS version (iOS 5) to send an MMS using the MessageUI framework.

One potential workaround we've found was to create a "send MMS" screen, where a user can attach their selected audio / pxt, and then when the user hits the send button, make a call to a 3rd party MMS gateway to deliver the audio / image.